# Suddenly can't create local/remote git branches

Tags: git, shell, unix

Not sure how I've managed this but I can't create a local and remote branch anymore.

```
~/myapp(master) > git checkout -b new_feature origin/new_feature
fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/new_feature' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

I've tried re-cloning my app in case the .git directory was corrupted, but no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to be careful with the term "remote branch". It usually means a ref within your own repository, which refers to the most recently fetched position of a branch in a remote repository. It sounds like you're trying to actually create a branch *in the remote repository*; if it doesn't already exist there, you'll have to create it by pushing as described in the answers.

Comment: Jefromi, thanks but I'm confused about what you meant about remote branch "usually means a ref within your own repository". Isn't a branch in my own repository a local branch? In any case, you're right - the solution was to create a remote branch first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create a remote branch that way, you need to first do `git checkout -b new_feature` to create the new local branch and then `git push origin new_feature` to push the branch to the remote.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, spot on! I had wrongly assumed the remote branch was automatically created too. That command worked previously but in hindsight the remote branch must have already existed.

Answer (score 2):

Try one of these:

- To create a local branch: `git branch some_branch`
- To use (checkout) that branch (this is not automatic): `git checkout some_branch`
- To create a remote branch: `git push origin origin:refs/heads/some_branch`
- To checkout (and track) a remote branch (creating a local_branch if it does not exist yet): `git branch --track local_branch origin/remote_branch`

Comment: The first two can be done together as `git checkout -b some_branch`

Comment: Thanks Simon. Those commands look useful, particularly the last one.